# Javascript not working for printing data one after the other

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a JavaScript code that prints whatever is present in the body-tag again when you click on the add button. The basic idea is to add authors. For example suppose there is only 1 author then the user does not click on the add button but only selects whether he is a student or a teacher. Now suppose there are 3 authors for a particular instance then he selects whether he is a student or a teacher for author 1 and then clicks "add" button.Now the above set of questions again appears for author 2 and now user can select whether the 2nd author is student or teacher. For the 3rd author the user needs to click "add" again which appears below the 2nd author which allows user to click whether the 3rd author is student or teacher. Infact this can be carried out for *n* number of authors.Basically the authors should appear one after the other in sequence. I could only achive it for 1st user

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Authors</title>
    <script>
        function addauthor()
        {
            console.log('function is working');
            var no;
            but = document.getElementById("addauth");
            no = Number(but.value)+1;
            document.getElementById('next').innerHTML='<p><div>'+no+'</div>   \
            <p>Whom do you want to add ? </p>    \
            <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="student" onchange="showForm()">Student</label>     \
            <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="teacher" onchange="showForm()">Teacher</label>     \
            <div id=""></div>          \
            </p>      \
            <p id="next">   \
                <button id="addauth" onclick="addauthor()" value="'+no+'">Add</button>   \
            </p>';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p><div>1</div>
    <p>Whom do you want to add ? </p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="student" onchange="showForm()">Student</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="teacher" onchange="showForm()">Teacher</label>
    <div></div>
    </p>
    <p id="next">
        <button id="addauth" onclick="addauthor()" value="1">Add</button>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am a newbie to JavaScript. Although the code works partially I know the code is inefficient but I am not sure of how to do it. If anyone knows a better or an efficient method or algorithm please suggest me.

[This is where I am going wrong for author 3 and till author n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49wVK.png)

Comment: Have you tried debugging in the console?

Comment: Is there something that I can infer from debugging in the console because the function works fine except from printing one after the other

Comment: You could log what the innerHTML is after you set it. Then you can see that you are rewriting the element instead of concatenating to it.

Comment: Exactly, I am trying to rewrite the "add" button and place the body instead of "add" button because any ways the body again has an add button. If you feel from my description , that is not how javascript works please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on is that you are rewriting the `#next` html element instead of concatenating to it. You can concatenate to the HTML element. You also need to move the button outside of the logic you want to append to the DOM. I have put a wrapper around the elements requiring to be appended called `person-container`:

**HTML**

```
 <div id="person-container">
    <div>1</div>
    <p>Whom do you want to add ? </p>
    <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="student" onchange="showForm()">Student</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="teacher" onchange="showForm()">Teacher</label>
 </div>
 <p id="next">
     <button id="addauth" onclick="addauthor()" value="1">Add</button>
 </p>
```

**JS**

```
var no = 1;
function addauthor()
    {
        console.log('function is working');
        but = document.getElementById("addauth");
        no++;
        var newEle = document.createElement('div');
        newEle.classList.add = "person";
        newEle.innerHTML ='<br><div>'+no+'</div>   \
        <p>Whom do you want to add ? </p>    \
        <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="student" onchange="showForm()">Student</label>     \
        <label><input type="radio" name="add" value="teacher" onchange="showForm()">Teacher</label>     \
        <div id=""></div><br>';
        document.getElementById('person-container').appendChild(newEle);
    }
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gt4c6zpL/4/

Comment: Oh thanks the code is now perfectly working for me ,but I still have doubts what exactly happens when you replace #next html element? Is it that it remains at same place? Is it the reason why things are not printing one after the other? As  I mentioned in the comment above this is how I was thinking "rewriting the 'add' button and place the body instead of 'add' button because any ways the body again has an add button.so it will print one after the other"

Comment: Think of every time you run the innerHTML function, without concatenation, it cuts and pastes that code back into the same location. The number increments correctly, but to the same element.

Comment: Yea right that is where I went wrong... I got it thanks a lot

Comment: Note that you can also remove the use of a global variable which isn't recommending Javascript. Just pass the appropriate to the `addauthor()` function: https://jsfiddle.net/gt4c6zpL/3/

Comment: Wait, in the above code the "add" button prints for each author which is not correct ( Infact that is the reason I was actually trying to replace the add button in the first place with the body). It should keep the "add" button only for the last author.Any idea on how we can solve this problem?

Comment: Or is there any way to delete the previous add button and move on to the next one.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Move the button outside an element that will contain all of the new HTML code. Then append to this element.

Comment: Yea its working.Learnt a lot today.Thanks for the help